# How to record and playback with NAudio using AsioOut

Tags: c#, audio-recording, playback, naudio, asio

I'm trying to **get the sound input** and **send output directly** with less latency possible with C#.

I'm using the library **NAudio** that supports **ASIO** for better latency.

In particular, I use the **AsioOut** object for recording and another for playback initialized with a **BufferedWaveProvider**, which is filled in a Callback function: **OnAudioAvailable**, which allows me to use the ASIO buffers.

The problem is that I hear the sound with **various glitches** and with a **bit of delay**. I think the problem is in the function OnAudioAvailable where the buffer is filled with data taken as input from the sound card.

**Declarations:**

```
NAudio.Wave.AsioOut playAsio;
NAudio.Wave.AsioOut recAsio;
NAudio.Wave.BufferedWaveProvider buffer;
```

**Play procedure:**

```
if (sourceList.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;

int deviceNumber = sourceList.SelectedItems[0].Index;

recAsio = new NAudio.Wave.AsioOut(deviceNumber);
recAsio.InitRecordAndPlayback(null, 2, 44100); //rec channel = 1

NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat formato = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat();
buffer = new NAudio.Wave.BufferedWaveProvider(formato);

recAsio.AudioAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs>(OnAudioAvailable);

//Collego l'output col buffer
playAsio = new NAudio.Wave.AsioOut(deviceNumber);
playAsio.Init(buffer);

//Registro
recAsio.Play();
//Playback
playAsio.Play();
```

**OnAudioAvailable():**

```
//Callback
private unsafe void OnAudioAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs e)
{
    //Copio tutti gli elementi di InputBuffers in buf e li aggiungo in coda al buffer
    byte[] buf = new byte[e.SamplesPerBuffer];
    for (int i = 0; i < e.InputBuffers.Length; i++)
    {
        Marshal.Copy(e.InputBuffers[i], buf, 0, e.SamplesPerBuffer);
        //Aggiungo in coda al buffer
        buffer.AddSamples(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    }
}
```

**AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs definition:**

```
public AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs(IntPtr[] inputBuffers, int samplesPerBuffer, AsioSampleType asioSampleType);
public float[] GetAsInterleavedSamples();
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be using two instances of `AsioOut` for the same device. I'm surprised this works at all. Just use the one, with `InitRecordAndPlayback`.

For absolute minimal latency for pass-through monitoring, in `AudioAvailableEvent`, copy directly to the `OutputBuffers`, and set `WrittenToOutputBuffers = true`. This means you don't need a `BufferedWaveProvider`.

Also remember that any glitches are simply due to you not managing to process the AudioAvailable event quickly enough. When you're working with ASIO, you can be at very low latencies (e.g. sub 10ms), and can be dealing with lots of data (e.g. 96kHz sample rates, 8 channels of input and output). So you need to do a lot of moving of data in a short time window. With .NET, you have to factor in the unfortunate  fact that the garbage collector could kick in at any time and cause you to miss a buffer from time to time.

Comment: I understand what you say and in fact is just what I wanted to do, but still don't understand how .. I can't find any **OutputBuffers** and in **AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs** these two parameters doesen't exists. 
Can you tell me where to find it or maybe show me some piece of code? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: are you using the latest version of NAudio?

Comment: Thanks for making me notice that I was using an older version. 
But I still can't do what you said, because **OutputBuffers** always has **length=0** unlike **InputBuffers** which has **length=2**. So if I try to copy data between them, I get out of range.
What should I do? Probably I'm forgetting something important.

Comment: ah yes, it's a bit hacky working like this (need to clean up the API a lot for a future version). Pass in the buffered wave provider to InitRecordAndPlayback which will be used to determine the number of output channels you want, even though you won't actually be reading anything from it.

Comment: I tried to do as you told me, but I don't hear anything. Yet I have also checked with the debugger and it executes all instructions without errors. What did I do wrong?
**OnAudioAvailable:**
`for (int i = 0; i < e.InputBuffers.Length; i++)
    e.OutputBuffers[i] = e.InputBuffers[i];
e.WrittenToOutputBuffers = true;`

Comment: you're not actually copying any data there. This is low level coding, you have pointers to buffers, and you must use Marshal.Copy to copy bytes between them.