# Real time audio processing in c#

Tags: c#, naudio, audio-player, asio, guitar

I'm creating a simple guitar amp for a project of mine and I'm experiencing issues with the latency of real time output of the audio. I can input and output the audio but its delayed by about half a second.
The guitar is plugged in with just a usb into the pc and it takes the input just like a mic.

I am using NAudio to process this, and after abit of looking around ive started to use asio, id rather not use asio because of the drivers but I will if it comes down to it. I assume its not possible to get perfect real time, especially with such a simple setup. But what can I do to help reduce the latency?

Comment: Have you tried building your project in release mode?

Comment: There is no such thing as "real time" using Windows + C#/.Net. Closest you can get is "fast as possible".

Comment: Have you tried/seen [NAudio.ASIO](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio.Asio)? Might also be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543513/naudio-using-asio-to-record-audio-and-output-with-a-guitar